# What is the "best" canonical implementation of Equals() for reference types?

Tags: c#, .net, equals

Implementing Equals() for reference types is harder than it seems. My current canonical implementation goes like this:

```
public bool Equals( MyClass obj )
{
  // If both refer to the same reference they are equal.
  if( ReferenceEquals( obj, this ) )
    return true;

  // If the other object is null they are not equal because in C# this cannot be null.
  if( ReferenceEquals( obj, null ) )
   return false;

   // Compare data to evaluate equality    
   return _data.Equals( obj._data );
}

public override bool Equals( object obj )
{
  // If both refer to the same reference they are equal.
  if( ReferenceEquals( obj, this ) )
    return true;

  // If the other object is null or is of a different types the objects are not equal. 
  if( ReferenceEquals( obj, null ) || obj.GetType() != GetType() )
    return false;

  // Use type-safe equality comparison
  return Equals( (MyClass)obj );
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
  // Use data's hash code as our hashcode  
  return _data.GetHashCode();
}
```

I think that this covers all corner (inheritance and such) cases but I may be wrong. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a fairly comprehensive guide to this a while back. For a start your equals implementations should be shared (i.e. the overload taking an object should pass through to the one taking a strongly typed object). Additionally you need to consider things such as your object should be immutable because of the need to override GetHashCode. More info here:

http://gregbeech.com/blog/implementing-object-equality-in-dotnet

Comment: My implementation is "shared". As you can see, at the end of Equals(Object) there is a call to Equals(MyClass).
I am aware of the mutability and GetHashCode() issues; but it is a an important observation. It has bit me several times. Too bad that there's no "easy" way to declare read only "classes".

Answer (score 1):

Better hope that this._data is not null if it's also a reference type.

```
public bool Equals( MyClass obj )
{
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return (this._data != null && this._data.Equals( obj._data ))
                         || obj._data == null;
    }
}

public override bool Equals( object obj )
{
    if (obj == null || !(obj is MyClass)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return this.Equals( (MyClass)obj );
    }
}

public override int GetHashCode() {
    return this._data == null ? 0 : this._data.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: You are right. This is just a "canonical" implementation to prove the concepts behind "Equals". My "real" implementation usually is implemented using Equals(a,b) instead of a.Equals(b).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you're writing a value type or a reference type.  For a sortable value type, I recommend this:
[A code snippet for Visual Studio 2005 that implements a skeleton value type adhering to Framework Design Guidelines](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2006/03/25/a-code-snippet-for-visual-studio-2005-that-implements-a-skeleton-value-type-adhering-to-framework-design-guidelines.aspx)

Comment: I know that the implementation for value types is different. I did ask about reference types.

Comment: -1 as pointed out the original question was specific to reference types, so this answer doesn't add anything.

Comment: @cori if you compare writing a reference Equals to a value Equals and you've turned out that you've written a value equals on a reference then it might be wrong.  So, in that respect, there is some value.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning inheritance, I think you should just let the OO paradigm does its magic.

Specifically, the `GetType()` check should be removed, it might break polymorphism down the line.

Comment: I disagree. Imagine that we have Apple and  Orange classes which derive from the Fruit class. If we remove the GetType() check in the implementation of Equals in Fruit, we could compare Apples to Oranges unless every derived class properly overrides Equals() too. It could get messy very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with chakrit, objects of different types should be allowed to be semantically equal if they have the same data or ID.

Personally, I use the following:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as MyClass;
        if (other == null) return false;

        return this.data.Equals(other.data);
    }
```

Comment: I disagree with you. This would allow us to compare Apples to Oranges.

Comment: The point is that maybe you do want them to be equal. The GetType check won't allow the use of proxies, for example; you'll have 2 identical objects, one wrapped inside a container of a different type, but you want to identify them as the same.

Comment: @SantiagoPalladino: It often makes sense to define equality comparers which use a looser definition of equivalence than `Object.Equals`.  For example, .net defines various case-insensitive string comparers that would regard "HELLO" as equivalent to "Hello" or "heLlO", even though the strings are different.  Such comparers could accept as equal objects as different types.  I very much dislike the notion of objects overriding `Object.Equals` to define an equivalence relation that is so loose as to allow objects of different types to compare unequal, unless one explicitly provides for...

Comment: ...the possibility that calling `X.Equals(Y)` may require `X` to call `Y.Equals(X)` if `Y` is an instance of a more-derived type than `X`.  Otherwise, if a proxy knows how to compare itself to an object, but an object doesn't know how to compare itself with the proxy, the `Equals` method would not define a proper recurrence relation (which, by definition, should be reflexive).

Answer (score 0):

As the link in the accepted answer by Greg Beech is broken, I hope this answer might be helpful to some.

Microsoft's documentation provides the following example for a typical implementation of `Equals()` on reference types (i.e. class):

```cs
public override bool Equals(object obj) => this.Equals(obj as TwoDPoint);

public bool Equals(TwoDPoint p)
{
   if (p is null)
   {
         return false;
   }

   // Optimization for a common success case.
   if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, p))
   {
         return true;
   }

   // If run-time types are not exactly the same, return false.
   if (this.GetType() != p.GetType())
   {
         return false;
   }

   // Return true if the fields match.
   // Note that the base class is not invoked because it is
   // System.Object, which defines Equals as reference equality.
   return (X == p.X) && (Y == p.Y);
}
```

The complete example with more details including what to do in derived classes or for structs, can be found at ["How to define value equality for a class or struct (C# Programming Guide)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type)

As an alternative to what is described in Microsoft's doc, the method `GetHashCode()` can also be implemented as follows:

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
   return HashCode.Combine(X, Y);
}
```